# Calling multiple web services asynchronously from a web page

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asynchronous

Can I make an asynchronous call from one web service to another web service deployed on different server?

The scenario is that an ASP.NET webforms page will call a web service in an async manner. This particular web service will then make another async call to a second web service deployed on different web server.

This this possible to achieve, and what additional steps or code would be necessary to make this happen?

Comment: Are these WCF web services, or legacy ASMX web services?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be any more difficult than just calling the initial web service in the first place.  Website A has a reference to WebService B and makes a call to that service (in response to some kind of action on Website A).  WebService B has a reference to WebService C and makes a call to that service (in response to the action being invoked by Website A).  Website A shouldn't know/care anything about WebService C, and vice/versa.

Or do A and C actually need to know about each other in your scenario?  If so, that changes things.